# Execute command with stdin written programmatically and connected to os.stdin

Tags: go

I am executing the docker-compose executable from my Go program. To configure it I pipe the docker-compose configuration directly to the stdin of docker-compose. This works fine for most cases, the code looks roughly like the following (I removed all error handling in the code snippets for simplicity):

```
args = append([]string{"-f", "-"}, args...)
cmd := exec.Command("docker-compose", args...)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(input)
cmd.Run()
```

`args` are the arguments passed to docker-compose, `input` is the docker-compose config as a YAML string.

While this works for most cases, it fails with commands that are interactive. Stdin is not connected to the os.stdin, and the commands fail. I can get interactive commands to work with the following code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker-compose", args...)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Run()
```

But this is without piping the configuration in, which I need to do in the end. I tried to combine these versions in some way, but couldn't get this to work:

```
input, _ := getDockerComposeAsYaml(config)
args = append([]string{"-f", "-"}, args...)
cmd := exec.Command("docker-compose", args...)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()

go func() {
    //defer stdin.Close()
    io.WriteString(stdin, input)
}()
cmd.Run()
```

I tried the above code with and without closing stdin explicitly, though the desired behaviour should be without closing it, as I want to keep stdin open for interactive use. Without closing the program just hangs forever, with closing stdin it doesn't work interactively as expected.

What is the correct way to have the stdin of an executed program connected to the os.stdin, while still being able to pipe in some data at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goroutine that writes to `stdin` (the pipe created with `cmd.StdinPipe`) should:

1. Write the `input` string
2. Then loop on the real `os.Stdin`, writing everything it gets into `stdin`
3. When EOF is encountered on `os.Stdin`, close `stdin` explicitly.

However, the subprocess may exit before `os.Stdin` is closed. In that case the pipe (`stdin` will be closed by `exec.Command`). Your loop should check for a closed `stdin` and exit the goroutine if that happens.